# Springboot same annotation call. the variable member value is 0

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependency-injection

My depedency injection @repository gives 0 value with @autowired

```
@Repository
public class AbsensiRepo{
public double jarakStandardMasukDanPulang = 4.5;
}

@Repository
public class RekapKehadiranRepo {
@Autowired
AbsensiRepo absensiRepo;

 public double ShowOtherDIVariable(){
  double test = 1*absensiRepo.jarakStandardMasukDanPulang;
  return test;
 }
}
```

when i run ShowOtherDIVariable()
the result is 0; and the variable absensiRepo.jarakStandardMasukDanPulang has value 0.

Why is that? is the jarakStandardMasukDanPulang  from class AbsensiRepo is not finished yet when i call it?

how to solve it, so the absensiRepo.jarakStandardMasukDanPulang value will be 4.5 like its original?

Comment: How do you call `ShowOtherDIVariable` and how do you get hold of the instance? Are all your repositories picked up by your class path scan?

Comment: Please note that field injection is [generally not recommended](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-constructor-vs-setter-injection). Not an answer, but maybe that already nudges you in the right direction.

Comment: Why use @Repository annotation when you can use `@Configuration`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the @Repository annotation. All that you need to do was to let Spring create bean for the 2 classes. Changing the annotation from `@Repository` to `@Configuration` will work.

```html
@Configuration
public class Test {
  @Autowired
  Test2 absensiRepo;

  public double showOtherDiVariable() {
    double test = 1 * absensiRepo.jarakStandardMasukDanPulang;
    return test;
  }
}
```

```html
@Configuration
class Test2 {
  public double jarakStandardMasukDanPulang = 4.5;
}
```

Comment: No, field initializers will be executed, regardless of which constructor is called. Doesn't matter if it is the auto-generated no-args constructor or a custom constructor. Field initializers are always executed. Try it out: `class A { public int x = 42; public static void main(String args[]) { System.out.println(new A().x); } }`

Comment: You are right. The problem was with the @Repository annotation. Changing that to `@Configuration` fixed the issue.

Comment: @knittl Halo knittl. Malathi solution seems working for my case. Since im new in spring boot, do you have more efficient solution to solve my case?